# Flutter How to save Image file to new folder in gallery?

Tags: image, flutter

I want to save the image in the gallery after I get the file from the camera, how to create a new directory and save the image file that we have obtained from the camera?

```
 Future getImageCamera() async {
var imageFile = await ImagePicker.pickImage(
    source: ImageSource.camera, maxHeight: 20.0, maxWidth: 20.0);

DateTime ketF = new DateTime.now();
String baru = "${ketF.year}${ketF.month}${ketF.day}";

//proses kompres
final temDirk = await getTemporaryDirectory();
final pathss = temDirk.path;

int rand = new math.Random().nextInt(100000);

//mengganti nama file
// String juduld = controllerJudul.text;

img.Image gambard = img.decodeImage(imageFile.readAsBytesSync());
img.Image gambarKecilx = img.copyResize(gambard,
    700); //parameter awal adalah sumber gambar // parameter kedua ukuran width, hp=>1k

var kompresimg = new File("$pathss/image_$baru$rand.jpg")
  ..writeAsBytesSync(img.encodeJpg(gambarKecilx, quality: 95));

setState(() {
  _gambar = kompresimg;
  namafile = "image_$baru$rand.jpg";
});
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to save the image into external storage directory for showing the image on gallery.
Instead of getting temporary directory, obtain external storage directory.

```
final directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

You need to provide the permission on `AndroidManifest.xml` file of your `android/app/src/main` folder

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

then let's say that you want to create a folder named MyImages and add the new image to that folder,

```
final myImagePath = '${directory.path}/MyImages' ;
final myImgDir = await new Directory(myImagePath).create();
```

then write to the file to the path.

```
var kompresimg = new File("$myImagePath/image_$baru$rand.jpg")
  ..writeAsBytesSync(img.encodeJpg(gambarKecilx, quality: 95));
```

for getting the number of files, just obtain the files to a list and check the length of the list

```
var listOfFiles = await myImgDir.list(recursive: true).toList();
var count = countList.length;
```

Comment: thats work.. than how to count file in that folder? @Krishnakumar CN

Comment: yes it's done  and add this img.Image images = img.decodeImage(kompresimg.readAsBytesSync());
    new File('${testdir.path}/image_$baru$rand.jpg')
      ..writeAsBytesSync(img.encodePng(images));

Comment: @krishnakumarcn - how can we write a video file? please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: You can reuse this method regardless of the file type. Make sure you are providing the correct file extension. @Kamlesh

Comment: The solution provided is going to create a folder on internal storage under android/data/[packagename]/MyImages. Moreover, all these photos wont be visible in the gallery/photos app.