# Saving Image captured from camera into gallery

Tags: flutter

I got my image by using Camera plugin in flutter. But that is saving somewhere, so i could not access the image outside. I want to save it to my gallery. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flutter How to save Image file to new folder in gallery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54565279/flutter-how-to-save-image-file-to-new-folder-in-gallery)